# Handing in the attached paper on my passport

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports, borders, overstaying

I am Brazilian and I was in Canada for studies. Since I have a US visa, I came to New York for a few days by car just to visit my cousin. Today I'll head back to Canada by bus and I am wondering what to do with that paper that the American immigration attached to my passport... I mean, I know I have to hand it in when leaving the USA, because that's the only way the American immigration will know that I left before my legal staying limit (6 months).

Since I don't know if the bus will actually make a stop at the border (where I would be able to hand this thing in), I am wondering if I can do this through a Canadian airport. Can I? Because I'm returning to Brazil next week by plane, from Toronto Pearson Airport.

I'm worried that the American immigration might think I overstayed, which would cause me a lot of headache when trying to come back in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would a buss cross an international border without making a small stop for immigration? They would surely know that not all passengers are visa free. I bet they do stop

Comment: @HankyPanky indeed.  Even visa-free passengers need to be inspected by immigration officers.

Comment: @HankyPanky: Maybe he means that it doesn't stop at US immigration. It just stops at Canadian immigration.

Answer (score 3):

The bus *must* stop at the border. When that happens, a custom offer goes through the bus asking to see each person's passport. Canadians get let though without further process but almost everyone else is told to get off the bus to line up at immigration counters inside. If for some reason they do not ask you to get out of the bus, that is the time to hand in your form. Otherwise, you will be asked for it at immigration.

See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44389/where-to-return-i-94-form) if you forget to return the form or for some reason, it happens differently.